# I'm trying a new command, but for some reason I'm getting an error. `TypeError: db.startsWith is not a function`

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying a new command, but for some reason I'm getting an error. `TypeError: db.startsWith is not a function`. Please check the code provided below. Thank you! :) Version: 7.1.1

```
if(args[0] == 'car') {
   let cars = db.startsWith(`car_${message.guild.id}`, { sort: '.data'})
      let content = "";

   for (let i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
      let user = client.users.get(cars[i].ID.split('_')[2]).username

   content += `${i+1}. ${user} ~ ${cars[i].data}\n`
  }
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer with package version info, are you using QuickDB? If so, what version are you currently using? From version 7.XX, `startsWith` was removed from their API.

In their Github, if you compare tag 6.1.1 with current you'll see this change: https://github.com/TrueXPixels/quick.db/tree/6.1.1/src/functions.

Comment: I edited it, and I am using v7.1.1 (quick.db)

Comment: Depending on if you like a challenge or not, the simplest approach would be dropping from 7.1.1 to an earlier version, however this may lead to support issues in future (if that matters to you), alternatively, reimplement the startsWith method, maybe using the `.get` method? The last version with `startsWith` (that worked on my local machine), is `7.0.0-bc21`, update package.json with: ` "quick.db": "7.0.0-b21"` in your list of `dependencies`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.startsWith` was removed. Alternative version is `db.all().filter(a => a.ID.startsWith(""))`